# net file - no entries found in the list

Tags: windows, csv, powershell

I am looking to close any open files on my PC via PowerShell, but when I use the

```
net file
```

command it says:

> There are no entries in the list.

I wish to close a CSV file which is open.

Comment: [Be warned](https://technet.microsoft.com/magazine/2009.04.windowsconfidential.aspx) about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`net file` lists files that are opened remotely (via a folder you shared). To list files that are opened locally you need something like [`handle.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle). [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer) also provides this functionality.